# Crash happen when integrate CardIO into my application

Tags: opencv

I integrate the cardio sdk into my application, however i got the crash bugs from the opencv inside the lib.

In my application: I have static opencv 2.4.0, i used it for Face Recognition, so i can't update to new version.

When i integrate cardio, and run my app, app crash when it detected the credit card.

Here is my crash log

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (k == GPU_MAT) in getGpuMatRef, file /Users/brluk/Code/OpenCV-iOS/opencv-svn/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1679
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/brluk/Code/OpenCV-iOS/opencv-svn/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1679: error: (-215) k == GPU_MAT in function getGpuMatRef

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks all.

Comment: for me also same problem, please let me know if you found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download **CardIO SDK** instead of add into pod, add CardIO lib directly into your project and add required frameworkrs.

2.Add "**OpenCV**" into your pod file.

3.Goto terminal cd project directory

4.run **pod install**

You can test your app now, i hope it should work. Thats how i resolved same issue in my case.